# How to convert my slider HTML into php wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress, slider

Basically I am trying to convert my slider HTML into php wordpress. My index.php is look like this and it’s no problem at all and it works fine:

```
            <div class="sl-slider">

                <div class="sl-slide" data-orientation="horizontal" data-slice1-rotation="-25" data-slice2-rotation="-25" data-slice1-scale="2" data-slice2-scale="2">
                    <div class="sl-slide-inner">
                        <div class="bg-img bg-img-1"></div>
                        <h2 class="top-title">A bene placito.</h2>
                        <blockquote><p>You have just dined, and however scrupulously the slaughterhouse is concealed in the graceful distance of miles, there is complicity.</p><cite>Ralph Waldo Emerson</cite></blockquote>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="sl-slide" data-orientation="vertical" data-slice1-rotation="10" data-slice2-rotation="-15" data-slice1-scale="1.5" data-slice2-scale="1.5">
                    <div class="sl-slide-inner">
                        <div class="bg-img bg-img-2"></div>
                        <h2 class="top-title">Regula aurea.</h2>
                        <blockquote><p>Until he extends the circle of his compassion to all living things, man will not himself find peace.</p><cite>Albert Schweitzer</cite></blockquote>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="sl-slide" data-orientation="horizontal" data-slice1-rotation="3" data-slice2-rotation="3" data-slice1-scale="2" data-slice2-scale="1">
                    <div class="sl-slide-inner">
                        <div class="bg-img bg-img-3"></div>
                        <h2>Dum spiro, spero.</h2>
                        <blockquote><p>Thousands of people who say they 'love' animals sit down once or twice a day to enjoy the flesh of creatures who have been utterly deprived of everything that could make their lives worth living and who endured the awful suffering and the terror of the abattoirs.</p><cite>Dame Jane Morris Goodall</cite></blockquote>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="sl-slide" data-orientation="vertical" data-slice1-rotation="-5" data-slice2-rotation="25" data-slice1-scale="2" data-slice2-scale="1">
                    <div class="sl-slide-inner">
                        <div class="bg-img bg-img-4"></div>
                        <h2>Donna nobis pacem.</h2>
                        <blockquote><p>The human body has no more need for cows' milk than it does for dogs' milk, horses' milk, or giraffes' milk.</p><cite>Michael Klaper M.D.</cite></blockquote>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="sl-slide" data-orientation="horizontal" data-slice1-rotation="-5" data-slice2-rotation="10" data-slice1-scale="2" data-slice2-scale="1">
                    <div class="sl-slide-inner">
                        <div class="bg-img bg-img-5"></div>
                        <h2>Acta Non Verba.</h2>
                        <blockquote><p>I think if you want to eat more meat you should kill it yourself and eat it raw so that you are not blinded by the hypocrisy of having it processed for you.</p><cite>Margi Clarke</cite></blockquote>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /sl-slider -->
```

But when I converted like this (with the same file index.php) :

```
<?php global $query_string;
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'post_type' => 'slides');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :?>

        <div id="slider" class="sl-slider-wrapper "> 

            <div class="sl-slider">
                <div class="sl-slide" data-orientation="horizontal" data-slice1-rotation="-25" data-slice2-rotation="-25" data-slice1-scale="2" data-slice2-scale="2">
                    <?php while ( $loop-> have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="sl-slide-inner">
                        <div class="bg-img bg-img-1"><?php the_post_thumbnail('featured_portfolio'); ?></div>
                        <h2 class="top-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                        <blockquote><p>You have just dined, and however scrupulously the slaughterhouse is concealed in the graceful distance of miles, there is complicity.</p><cite>Ralph Waldo Emerson</cite></blockquote>

                    </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /sl-slider -->

                <div id="nav-dots" class="nav-dots">
                <span class="nav-dot-current"></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                </div>
        </div><!-- /slider-wrapper -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Trouble comes. I can’t get same result as before I converted, can you help me ? 
[This is the result I get](http://www.yohaa.hol.es)

Answer (score 0):

It seems more a jQuery problem instead of php issue, like jQuery connot fire the right div to start the slider. Try to add less complicated markup like adding just the title, and make jQuery select the slider div.

Comment: unfortunately, it sounds like your on the right lines and despite your reputation, this is a commentary answer. Perhaps you could add some context/code/examples.. Something to make it an actual answer